# How to make an item unfocusable in css

Tags: html, css, haml, tabindex

I have a menu that is hidden in mobile view of application and viewable in desktop view. So since it's not activated the items in that menu shouldn't be focused when tab through but they are tab-able when the menu is hidden.

This is what I see in `applicantion.html.haml`

```
......
    .page-layout
      .page-layout-sidebar
        =link_to '/', class: "page-Branding page-Branding--secondary" do
          = image_tag site_logo_src, alt: 'Logo'
        %nav.page-Layout-nav{'aria-label' => 'Primary Navigation', 'role' => 'navigation'}
          %ul.topia-Nav
            - feature :item1 do
              %li
                =link_to t('menu.item1'), root_path, { :class => 'page-Nav-action'}
            - feature :item2 do
              %li
                =link_to t('menu.item2'), item2_path, { :class => 'page-Nav-action'}
......
```

I did inspect on page and I see page-Nav-action in multiple css files. I tried using `tabindex: -1` in html it works in mobile view but then in desktop view I can't tab through menu items. Also `tabindex` is HTML attribute so can't use in CSS. I am guessing I have make changes from CSS. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How does the menu get hidden?

Comment: That's... not HTML.

Comment: There are some media queries that hide that.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan sorry i am new to HTML and CSS

Comment: I've guessed that the language is HAML, due to the file name ending. Please do make sure you use the appropriate tags.

Answer (score 0):

`tabIndex` is the value you need in HTML. Setting to `-1` will make sure the tab button will not focus the element. There's no supported method to do this in CSS. You can toggle the `tabIndex` value in Javascript.

```
window.onresize = function(){
    if(this.innerWidth > 500){
        tabIndexes(0)
    } else {
        tabIndexes(-1)
    }
}

function tabIndexes(index){
    var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
    for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) inputs[i].tabIndex = index;
}
```